# Android Location in background

Tags: android, geolocation

i'm new in java/android app and i'm creating an app that uses user-location. I want the location to be updated at the begining of the app.
The problem is that my location class is an activity and i don't want to show another contentview for this class.
Actually, i want the location thing to be done in background, without changing the UI, in a separated class.

Is it possible? How?

Thanks :P

Comment: In Android O above code is not work. Check my comments in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51187231/get-locationupdates-in-background-service-countinuously/51188196#51188196.

Comment: In Android O above code is not work. Check my comments in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51187231/get-locationupdates-in-background-service-countinuously/51188196#51188196

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to put the location in a different activity, the LocationManager already  does it in the background:

```
public void getLocation(){
    lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    gpsLocationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    //do something with the new location
        if (location != null)
            gpsLocation = location;

        }
    };

      gpsLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);


      lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1, 0, gpsLocationListener);



}
```

Comment: The problem is that i cant put that in another class that does not extends Activity, can i ?

Comment: You can, for example, put it in a class that extends a Service

Comment: I didnt know about services. You...i just love you. Thanks :P

Answer (score 3):

Using the [LocationManager](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html) you should be able to use what ever kind of activity (or service) you want.